# Libre Office Won't Give Me A Black Font

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am trying to edit a document in Libre'Office which was...

- Originally created by me in Libre'Office
- Sent to another person who edited it in Microsoft Word
- Returned to me with her request that I accept the changes

I Accepted the changes, and am now trying to edit it some more.

The entire document has changed the fonts to a Mustard/Yellow/Sand sort of color, and Libre'Office will not accept my instructions to change it to black.

The keystroke sequence that I'm using is

- *Format*
- *Character*
- *Font Effects*
- *Font Color*
- *(Choose Black)*
- *Hit OK button*

No matter what color I choose, the font won't change.

I tried looking at the Libre'Writer help page [HERE](https://help.libreoffice.org/swriter/cui/ui/effectspage/fontcolorlb?Language=en-US&System=WIN&Version=4.3#bm_id0123200902114658) on their site.

Best I can tell, I'm following the rules.

Any ideas will be welcome.